# Android Gradle 'versionCode' not read from environment variable

Tags: android, gradle, automation

I have an Android that I deploy to a Google Play alpha track trough a CI server. For the Android `versionCode` I make use of the CI build number that I inject into the Gradle script through an environment variable.

This used to work fine; but currently Google Play is not accepting any builds. When I manually trigger a alpha upload build (using the [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) plugin) for Gradle I eventually end up with the following error:

```
APK has an invalid version code.
```

So when looking (using `aapt dump badging apk-path`) at the generated APK I see an empty value for the version code (`versionCode=''`).

The relevant code from the build script:

```
def appVersionCode = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 0
defaultConfig {
  ...
  versionCode appVersionCode
  ...
}
```

It seems the variable is not read correctly; however it reads `System.getenv("KEY_PASS")` correctly to use for signing.

The variable is also set:

```
❯ echo $BUILD_NUMBER
1234
```

Does anyone have an idea why this specific variable doesn't seem to be read (anymore)?

Gradle version: 3.5 with Android Gradle plugin 2.3.1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to change your code to this:

```
def appVersionCode = Integer.valueOf(System.env.BUILD_NUMBER ?: 0)
defaultConfig {
  ...
  versionCode appVersionCode
  ...
}
```

Comment: better using def appVersionCode = Integer.valueOf(System.env.BUILD_NUMBER ?: 1) since a versioncode of 0 is invalid.